# Ignoring certain number of rows while reading text file

Tags: matlab, text, import

I want to read a text file in matlab, but when I read I want to ignore a certain number of headers, the number shouldn't be fixed. Then I want to start reading from the last non-deleted row to a certain number of line again. So for example, I may want to ignore the first 7 rows and starting from the 8th row to the next 100 rows.

How can I do that easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Post any code you tried, or reasearch you did; don't expect an entire answer to written for you from scratch

Comment: Well I exceeded the expectations in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a text file data.txt with `N_header` number of headerlines containing 5 integers per row and you want to read N_lines from this file.

First create a link to the file so MatLab knows what file you need:

```
FID = fopen('data.txt') % Create a file id
```

Now you can use textscan to read N_lines lines and skipping N_header headerlines:

```
N_header = 7;
N_lines = 100;

formatSpec = '%d %d %d %d %d'; % Five integers per row seperated by whitespace
C = textscan(FID,formatSpec,N_lines,'HeaderLines',N_header);

fclose(FID)
```

The columns in your text file are stored in C{column number}. If you want to have each line stored in C use:

```
formatSpec = '%s'; % The whole string, i.e. each line
C = textscan(FID,formatSpec,N_lines,'delimiter','\n','HeaderLines',N_header); % Up to the line end '\n'
```

Which stores every line in cell array C.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function which reads line by line:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html

If you read it in a loop, whenever you reach unwanted line, just skip it using `continue`.